# A slightly tricky inequality

Tags: inequality

I suspect the answer to this will be obvious once I see it, but I can't seem to solve for $\phi$ here:

$$ -1.96 \leq \frac{6.4-10\phi}{\sqrt{1-\phi^2}} \leq 1.96  $$

Wolfram gives me $.467=\frac{40000-49\sqrt{39301}}{64901}\leq \phi\leq \frac{40000+49\sqrt{39301}}{64901}=.766$ but won't tell me how.

I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve this. I am having trouble dealing with the $\phi$ term in the denominator.

Regards

Edit:

Squaring and multiplying by 100 gives me $0 \leq \frac{10000\phi^2-6400\phi+4096)}{(1-\phi^2)} \leq 384.16$

Nothing seems to factor and if I multiply everything by $(1-\phi^2)$ I get $0\leq 10000\phi^2-6400\phi+4096\leq384.16-384.18\phi^2$

Now if I try to deal with the $\phi^2$ in the right hand side by subtraction, won't I simply end up creating a $-\phi^2$ term on the left hand side? I can't seem to isolate $\phi$

Answer (score 2):

Hint squaring both sides and multiplying by $100 $ and solving lhs , rhs inequality simultaneously gives you the desired answer. As per your edit now separate equalities and then use quadratic formula which is $$\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ this is generalized formula for a general quadratic which is $ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: Thanks, but I am still having trouble. Please take a look at my edited question.

Comment: I have edited take a look at iy

Answer (score 0):

Take each side separately.  Squaring will give you a quadratic.
$$-1.96=\frac {6.4-10\phi}{\sqrt {1-\phi^2}}\\
1.96^2(1-\phi^2)=6.4^2-128\phi+100\phi^2\\
(100+1.96^2)\phi^2-128\phi+(6.4^2-1.96^2)=0\\
\phi=\frac{64 \pm\sqrt{64^2-(100+1.96)^2(6.4^2-1.96^2)}}{100+1.96^2}$$
Now choose the proper sign and do the other side the same way.